# Freebase Query Limit

Tags: freebase, mql

I have been trying to query freebase (on freebase.com) for all instances of **/organization/organization**

```
[{
  "type": "/organization/organization",
  "name": null,
  "mid": null,
  "limit": 1,000,000
}]
```

but no matter how much limit i put I get maximum result of 100,000. I wish to get list of all topics. Is there a way to circumnavigate that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Google has a limit of 100k quota. It wasnt mentioned on freebase.com. It was mentioned on the google freebase page!